# Substitution of queueEvent when not using GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

When controlling OpenGL from other threads, if it is GLSurfaceView, we use queueEvent(). Then, in cases where OpenGL is created on SurfaceView (use eglCreateWindowSurface, eglMakeCurrent, etc.), how should I implement for operating OpenGL from other threads?

Comment: I am facing a very, very similar problem where I have to draw a 3D scene while loading assets. If I can find anything useful, I will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own `queueEvent`.

1. Make a queue. (`ArrayList<Runnable> mQueue`)
2. `queueEvent()` adds `Runnable` instances to this queue(`mQueue`).
3. Your `SurfaceView`'s rendering thread pops `event` from the queue.
4. invokes `event.run()`

Use locks (`synchronized` or explicit locks) to avoid problems.

In `GLSurfaceView`, there are 3 and 4 steps in a loop of GLThread and `mQueue` is protected by `synchronized` blocks.

see also: [GLSurfaceView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/bf35112b2835201ab007b33c3a2cb3b9e6a6d166/opengl/java/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.java)

PS: sorry for my poor english.